# Нужна регулярка для разбиения матрицы заданной в скобках

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения, матрицы

Дана матрица, заданная в скобках `{{2,3},{4,5}}`
Нужна регулярка чтобы получить `0=> 2,3 1=> 4,5`
Далее уж сам по запятым разобью.
Сам смог только получить `{{2,3}` и `{4,5}`, обрезать скобки думаю неправильным, потому нужна помощь с правильной регуляркой.

Comment: тут скорее нужна не регулярка, а парсер. {{2,3},{4,5}} напоминает JSON - хотя возможно нужно будет заменить фигурные скобки на квадратные.

Comment: не, напоминает лишь скобками. JSON содержит параметр:значение.тут нет.

Comment: Укажите предпочитаемый язык (в тегах не указан и в вопросе тоже). Регулярка - это хорошо. Только в одном случае нужно использовать split в другом replace а в третьем exec.

Comment: Тег не дал рейтинг поставить, комент был слишком короткий, а регулярки так и так везде примерно одни. Для JS Нужно.

Comment: Если вам нужен двумерный массив то самому строку разбирать не надо. замените фигурные скобки на квадратные, получите массив в формате JS. `var a=eval("{{2,3},{4,5}}".replace(/{/g,'[').replace(/}/g,']'))`

Comment: Вообще, да, нужен двумерный,но скобки это такая маленькая прихоть)
Работает верно, запишите как ответ, чтоб я мог отметить решением

Comment: Для решения влоб подойдет [регулярка](https://regex101.com/r/lU3sO0/1) `/\{([^{}]*?)\}/g` - она вычленит все не-скобочки внутри фигурных скобочек. Но решения не влоб - изящнее)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
eval($('#matrix-data').val().replace(/{/g,'[').replace(/}/g,']'));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var s = "{{2,3},{4,5}}";
var a1 = s.split(var a1 = s.split(/\{\{|\}\}|\}\,\{/g );//Разбить на два 
alert(a1.join('][') ); //[][2,3][4,5][]

var a2 = s.split(/[\{\}\,]+/g ); // Разбить на четыре (исправил)
alert(a2.join('][') ); // [][2][3][4][5][]
```

Вместо WScript.Echo в браузере нужен alert()
Как убрать первое и последнее пусто - не могу сказать

Comment: Тогда мы получим ["", "", "3", "4", "", "", "2", "1", "", ""]
а не 
0=> 2,3
1=> 4,5

Comment: Я понял, для браузера regex работает чуть по другому, сейчас добавлю другие варианты.